# Aligment of only 1 image is not correct

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some troubles with the aligment of one image, see here:

http://www.rowecobouw.nl/veel-verkochte-woningen/?preview=true

The problem can be seen in the 7th row.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Regards,
Jordy

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers". In other words, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The reason for the above quote is that once you have fixed the problem on your site, future readers of stackoverflow (who find your question through a search) will no longer be able to see exactly what the problem was... because it's no longer a problem

Comment: I would suggest you redo your whole design.. It might give you more problems in long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove float:left from .wp-caption and add display:inline-block;

```
.wp-caption { /* float: left;*/ display: inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove float left from .wp-caption  and add display:inline-block

```
 .wp-caption {
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid #eee;
   background: #fcfcfc;
   /* float: left; */
   display: inline-block;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height` on `.block-type-content div.entry-content, .block-type-content div.entry-content p` is throwing your `attachment ID's` out.

Reset your `line-height` and all is well.

Current CSS declaration:

```
.block-type-content div.entry-content, .block-type-content div.entry-content p {
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 180%;
}
```

Change to:

```
.block-type-content div.entry-content, .block-type-content div.entry-content p {
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

and you're good to go.